# Bootsplash setup with LUKS password prompt

Tags: boot, luks, theme, plymouth, bootsplash

I'm running manjaro with full disk encryption. I want to have "themed" boot experience and so I installed bootsplash. Unfortunately it doesn't theme the initial disk password prompt. Is it possible to do this with bootsplash or do I have switch to plymouth instead?

Secondary question: What's the effective difference between plymouth and bootsplash? On Debian based systems I always use plymouth, but the arch wiki says it's been superseded by bootsplash. The only thing I found is that it's supposed to slow the boot process down less.

Comment: I'd like to bump this question since I am experiencing the exact same issue. The manjaro wiki says that plymouth is widely replaced by bootsplash but a lot of sources state that only plymouth is able to handle luks password prompts. Seems odd, to replace an application with one that handles less cases. Many people also report issues with luks password prompts in bootsplash, requiring to swtich TTYs or install mkinitcpio-encrypt-bootsplash just to be able to enter the password.